# reposition different divs differently

Tags: css

I want to stack `div` differently for small screens and I want to use `css` for it.

What I want to achieve is following:

- for one page, the `div class="three` has to go UNDER the `.header`
- for another page (uses the same code), the `div class="two"` has to go ABOVE the `.header`

I only managed to make `.two` go above `.header`, but the result is that I cannot make the `.three` go below the `.header` on my other page (the actual result is that the `.three` is also placed ABOVE the `.header` because of my `css` code). How to fix?

```css
@media(max-width: 460px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .header {
        order: 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='header'>
            <div class="one">
                one
            </div>
            hello
        </div>
        <div class='sidebar'>
            <div class="two">
                two
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                three
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Such problems it is always best to have a clean html. Do you have any sort of limitation of manipulating the html and therefore are looking for a pure css solution?

Comment: Not possible with flexbox unless all the elements (header, two & three) are in a **single** flex container which is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is tricky because your HTML is grouping items two and three.

The very best solution is to rearrange your HTML.

Just in case that it is not possible, you can set a workaround with display: contents on the sidebar element (this makes the element disappear from the flow)

```css
@media(max-width: 4600px) {
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .header {
        order: 2;
    }
    .three {
        order: 3;
    }
    .sidebar {
        display: contents;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='header'>
            <div class="one">
                one
            </div>
            hello
        </div>
        <div class='sidebar'>
            <div class="two">
                two
            </div>
            <div class="three">
                three
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: I have changed the media query so that it shows the desired result at the snippet standard dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Your `two` and `three` are **within** in a div called `sidebar`. You can't remove them from this div and order them with `header` using CSS because `header` is not the same level as them. You should possibly consider re-structuring your HTML?

I have amended your example slightly to show you what I mean.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  order: 2;
}

.two {
  order: 1;
}

.three {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='header'>
      <div class="one">
        one
      </div>
      hello
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      two
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```